# Why can´t i animate the scali when i make another animation with keyframes?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-animations, keyframe

I want a picture to slide (with keyframes), and wen :hover that its scale grows, and when :active, decrease its scale. When i do so, it only slides, :hover and :active don´t work... Please help

```css
#slide-right {
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  height: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: .5s;
 animation: slide-right 1s ease-out both;
}

#slide-right:hover {
  transition: .5s;
  transform: scale(1.04);
}

#slide-right:active {
  transition: .2s;
  transform: scale(0.95);
}

@keyframes slide-right {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(+200px);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" id="slide-right">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because your key-frames animation is using css `transform` property and css for hover also uses `transform` to scale the image. So, only one of it will work at a time.

As a workaround for this problem, you can animate the entry of image using position.

Add `position:relative` to `#slide-right` and update your key-frames to `0%{left:0}` and `100%{left:200px}`.

For working example, please refer : [this](https://codepen.io/shubhamYerawar/pen/zJPEzg)

Answer (score 1):

```css
#slide-right {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  height: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: .5s;
 animation: slide-right 1s ease-out forwards;
}


@keyframes slide-right{
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 200px;
  }
}

#slide-right:hover {
  transition: .5s;
  transform: scale(1.04);
}

#slide-right:active {
  transition: .2s;
  transform: scale(0.95);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" id="slide-right">
```